# XPath fails because Namespace colon in Title

Tags: xpath

I'm generating an XML report, using the JDF standard for PDFs going into a printing workflow.
There are 3 "DPart" sections, and I can use an xPath query to recognize them, but I want to grab the "Separation" attribute of each "cip4:Part". I can also get a query to find that, but it does not distinguish between the multiple "DPart"s.

```
    <DPart End="0" ID="0003" ParentRef="0002" Start="0">
     <DPM>
       <cip4:Root>
         <cip4:Intent cip4:ProductType="ProductPart"/>
         <cip4:Production>
           <cip4:Resource>
             <cip4:Part Separation="K1"/>
             <cip4:Color cip4:ActualColorName="Black" cip4:ColorType="Normal">
           </cip4:Resource>
           <cip4:Resource>
             <cip4:Part Separation="S1"/>**
             <cip4:Color cip4:ActualColorName="Dieline" cip4:ColorType="Normal">
           </cip4:Resource>
           <cip4:Resource>
             <cip4:ColorantControl ColorantOrder="K1 S1" ColorantParams="K1 S1"/>
           </cip4:Resource>
           <cip4:Resource>
             <eg:InkCoverage>
               <eg:InkCov eg:Mm2="0.000000" eg:Pct="0.000000" eg:Separation="K1"/>
               <eg:InkCov eg:Mm2="182.337538" eg:Pct="0.721209" eg:Separation="S1"/>
             </eg:InkCoverage>
           </cip4:Resource>
         </cip4:Production>
       </cip4:Root>
     </DPM>
    </DPart>
```

I want to do something like:

```
/DPM[2]/*[name ()='cip4:Part'], but it's not working.
```

I'm in a low-code pre-press environment (Esko Automation Engine), but the system gives me tools to parse an xPath, and throw some JavaScript at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least three reasons your XPath selects nothing:

- `DPM` is not an immediate child of the root node
- There is only one `DPM`, so `DPM[2]` won't select anything
- There is no child of a `DPM` whose name is `cip4:Part`.

You also say in the narrative that there are three DPart's, which implies that `DPart` is not actually the outermost element as it appears to be in your sample. This makes it difficult to provide the correct XPath. However, you might be able to make a start with

```
(//DPM)[2]//*[name()='cip4:Part']
```

Comment: "There is only one DPM, so DPM[2] won't select anything"
It was just a snippet, because I didn't want to include the entire code. Your answer seems to be working, and I'm trying to integrate that into our workflow now.